# onMouseover compatibility with IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've made a map on which, when I point to a region a box pops up with some information.

It works on Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox or Internet explorer (it's at samtranum.com/border-barriers if you want to see it).

How can I make the code below work in Firefox and IE, too?

Javascript:

```
function showTooltip(div, title, desc) {
  var left = event.pageX - 200 + 'px'; 
  var top = event.pageY - 700 + 'px';
  div.style.display = 'inline';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.width = '200px';
  div.style.top = top;
  div.style.left = left;
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  div.style.border = 'solid 1px black';
  div.style.padding = '10px';
  div.innerHTML = '<b>' + title + '</b> <div style="padding-left:10; padding-right:5">' +     desc + '</div>';
} 
function hideTooltip(div) {
  div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

HTML:

```
<body> 
   <div style="display:none" id="t1"></div>

  <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/516faf88e4b03f8eb2807350/t/519f3bdee4b05327e360c53d/1369390047458/Borders_Map1.jpg" width="472" height="859" usemap="#bordermap"/>

<map name="bordermap">

<area shape="poly" coords="190,321,194,323,199,322,207,328,202,339,216,341,211,352,227,338,217,333,212,330,210,325,205,321,201,318" onMouseOut="hideTooltip(t1)" onMouseOver="showTooltip(t1, 'Central America', 'There is a barrier between Cuba and the American enclave in Guantanamo Bay, and there have been proposals for Belize-Guatemala and Costa-Rica-Nicaragua barriers.')">
```

etc. From here on down it's the same for each region.

Comment: Open the Error Console in FireFox and look for an Error message and write it here

Comment: Try using all lowercase letters for the attributes: `onmouseover`, `onmouseout`.

Comment: ...`showTooltip("t1", 'Central America'`...t1 in ""

Comment: @davidkonrad that wouldn't fix the issue because then you would do `"t1".style.display` which returns an error(`.style` is not a property of `string`)

Answer (score 1):

```
function showTooltip(id, title, desc) {
  var left = event.pageX - 200 + 'px',
      top = event.pageY - 700 + 'px',
      div = document.getElementById('t1');
  div.style.display = 'inline';
...
}
```

Try this one(same for `hide_tooltip`)

Comment: @yvytty in IE and Firefox, the page opens and looks fine, it's just that when I point to a region it an information box should pop up -- but it doesn't. Nothing happens.

Comment: @Johan Nordii There are dozens of error messages -- too many to post here. They seem to be focused on other pages on my site, though, not on this particular map I'm worried about.

Comment: LightStyle: I think you're saying I should define t1 by changing "id" to "div" in the first line and adding the fourth line you suggested. I tried that, but it didn't work. Just made the code stop working in Safari.

Comment: In HTML have you changed `onMouseOut="hideTooltip(t1)" onMouseOver="showTooltip(t1, ...` to `hideTooltip("t1")` and `showTooltip("t1", ...` ?

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this. It appears to be related to my efforts to get the div to appear near the cursor. When I remove the following lines, the div appears in Firefox (in a fixed position):                                var left = event.pageX + 'px'; var top = event.pageY + 'px'; div.style.top = top; div.style.left = left;